# How to prevent last screen from appearing after turning back on my computer

Tags: suspend, security, lock-screen

Each time I suspend my computer, after I turn it back on, the last screen state before suspension shows up in the blink of an eye - showing possibly web pages, terminals, applications etc. -, then the lock screen shows up and a password is required to access my computer.

I am using Ubuntu 18 but I encountered the same behavior with the former versions.

In most cases this can be seen as a minor problem but sometimes this can lead to some confidentiality issues.

Do you know why this is occurring and if it is possible to prevent it?

Comment: [Related reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/asfqni/desktop_is_visible_before_unlocking_lock_screen/)

Comment: I haven't read the reddit post, but have seen discussions on this in lp.bug.reports, and it's not the Ubuntu software directly that leads to this; it's a consequence of how some cards work (particularly memory usage) & it's hard to get a card to not display an image it wasn't instructed post-resume to display (it was in the cards memory and switching modes caused the card to display the old image). FYI: Ubuntu Core 18 shouldn't have that problem as it has no desktop being an IoT appliance release, it's usually reported in desktop releases.  Currently only the workarounds are available.

Comment: Might be useful the output of `inxi -SMG -! 31 -y 80`. Please tell us if still happen after [`xset -dpms`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xset.1.html) ([source](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=753678#c54))

Answer (score 0):

X11 automatic screenlocking is always risky. The only safe way to ensure your screen is locked when you resume is to lock your screen manually before suspending.